# iCarousel - Coverflow Vertical type - selected/highlighted image change to first instead of centre

Tags: ios, carousel, icarousel

I am using iCarousel in my application to show list of images in Coverflow - Vertical style with tilt=0, with the default implementation the centre image/view is getting highlighted. Instead I have a requirement to highlight the first image/view in Carousel, and the rest of the images/view will be shown below.

Could anyone help me in modifying the carousel.

Current Implementation:
[image]

Expected:

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot that u want and whats u are getting. I have worked many times with iCarousel I can help u better then.

Comment: Thanks Surbhi, I have updated the actual and expected image.

Comment: remove all sliders. It will hide those.

Comment: its just a reference image, in my actual screen sliders wont be there. my intention to show these images is, as per first image the highlighted image is in middle... but my expectation is like the second image. the highlighted one should be first one.

Comment: Try this 
- (NSInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(__unused iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //note: placeholder views are only displayed on some carousels if wrapping is disabled
    return 0;
}

Comment: Tried this already, not getting the desired result. no change in the UI. I have tried this with Inverted Time machine type, if there are 2/3 cards it is not showing all the items in the list. Kindly help me if this is possible with Custom type.

Comment: please share was your problem resolved. I am so sorry I was not following stackoverflow from some time.